# What is the simplest way to match the versions for Eigen and Ceres-Solver?

Tags: c++, homebrew, eigen, ceres-solver

I installed both Eigen and Ceres-Solver with brew as prerequisites for an existing project.

When I run make for the project, I get the following message

> Found Eigen dependency, but the version of Eigen found (3.3.1) does
>   not exactly match the version of Eigen Ceres was compiled with
>   (3.3.0). This can cause subtle bugs by triggering violations of the
>   One Definition Rule. See the Wikipedia article
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule for more details

My first idea was to compile Ceres-solver from source using the Eigen from brew, but this produced other error messages during make.

Specifically, it builds up to 54% and then prints

```
[ 54%] Linking C executable ../bin/curve_fitting_c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___kmpc_atomic_fixed4_sub", referenced from:
      __ZN5Eigen8internal29general_matrix_matrix_productIldLi1ELb0EdLi1ELb0ELi0EE3runElllPKdlS4_lPdldRNS0_15level3_blockingIddEEPNS0_16GemmParallelInfoIlEE in libceres.a(gradient_checker.cc.o)
      __ZN5Eigen8internal29general_matrix_matrix_productIldLi1ELb0EdLi0ELb0ELi0EE3runElllPKdlS4_lPdldRNS0_15level3_blockingIddEEPNS0_16GemmParallelInfoIlEE in libceres.a(dogleg_strategy.cc.o)

__ZN5ceres8internal11EventLoggerC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE in libceres.a(wall_time.cc.o)
  __ZN5ceres8internal11EventLoggerC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE in libceres.a(wall_time.cc.o)
  __ZN5ceres8internal11EventLoggerD2Ev in libceres.a(wall_time.cc.o)
```

... Skipping some lines ...

```
    __ZN5ceres8internal11EventLogger8AddEventERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE in libceres.a(wall_time.cc.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-3.5: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The [ceres installation page](http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html) recommends Eigen 3.2.2 or later, so 3.3.1 should be fine, unless there were some structural changes between 3.2 and 3.3.

**My Question:**

**What is the next step I should try? Installing an older version of Eigen?**

Comment: Well, you get a clear warning. What do you expect us to tell you? "No, the developers of that software had no idea how their software works?"

Comment: Okay fair point. I assumed the answer to the first question would be no, but I'm a bit stumped about what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to build ceres from source using [the instructions on the ceres website](http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html). I'm still not sure why this failed, but building from source using brew (an option that I did not previously know existed) works.

`brew install --build-from-source ceres-solver`

It uses the Eigen dependency installed via brew (Eigen 3.3.1) and does not produce any error messages.